# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.setElementConverter(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter;)V

Tags: appium-android

I am getting the following errror "
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.setElementConverter(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/internal/JsonToWebElementConverter;)V"

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>7.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.14.3</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
<version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
</dependency>
```

**The code as follows**

```
public class Bc {
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
@BeforeTest
public void setup()
{
try {
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator-5554");
dc.setCapability("platformName","android");
dc.setCapability("appPackage","com.android.calculator2");
dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),dc);
URL url= new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,dc);
MobileElement el1 = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElementById("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_2");
el1.click();
MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElementById("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_5");
el2.click();
MobileElement el3 = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("plus");
el3.click();
MobileElement el4 = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElementById("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_3");
el4.click();
MobileElement el5 = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElementById("com.android.calculator2:id/digit_9");
el5.click();
MobileElement el6 = (MobileElement) 
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("equals");
el6.click();
Assert.assertEquals
(driver.findElementById("com.android.calculator2:id/result").getText(),64);
}
catch (Exception exp) {
System.out.println("Cause is:"+exp.getCause());
System.out.println("Message is:"+exp.getMessage());
exp.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Test
public void sampletes()
{
System.out.println("im inside sample test");
}

@AfterTest
public void teardown() {

}
}
```

**I am getting following error**
   [it contains the error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGNsX.png)
   [it contains error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y54HM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The provided configuration contains incompatible dependencies.

Here is a dependency compatibility matrix:

```
|Appium Java client|Selenium Java client    | 
|------------------|------------------------| 
| 8.0.0            | 4.+ (preferred: 4.1.+) |
| 7.6.0            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.5.1            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.5.0            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.4.1            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.4.0            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.3.0            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.2.0            | 3.141.59               |
| 7.1.0            | 4.0.0-alpha-1          |
| 7.0.0            | 3.141.59               |
```

The version of Selenium Java client [was downgraded](https://github.com/appium/java-client/commit/f5470d9cf355e56023f4a14dba4e80af5ea840fc) in `7.2.0` because of [users complains](https://twitter.com/imalittletester/status/1162297550713622529).

Moreover Appium Java clients of `7.X.Y` version are not compatible with Selenium Java client of versions `4.0.0-alpha-2`, `4.0.0-alpha-3` because of [this change](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/96fec3ca49a1462c7881fcd0c06194cb565bdd2d#diff-fa76272f866d8067bb11a32f27773026) in Selenium java client.